# Django views 'int' object is not iterable error

Tags: django, django-views

Why does the error appear?

If call any of if blocks after `form.save()` appear the 'int' object is not iterable error

Code below:

```
if request.method =='POST':

     if form.is_valid():
         form.instance.user = request.user

         is_auction = request.POST.get("create_auction", "")
         phone_number = request.POST.get("phone", "")

         attr_dic = {}

         for attr in form.cleaned_data['subcategory'].attributes.all().order_by('ordering'):
            if request.POST.get(attr.name):
                attr_desc={}
                attr_desc['verbos_name'] = attr.verbos_name

                if attr.attr_type =='choice':
                    attr_desc['value'] = str(attr.dict.model_class().objects.get(pk=request.POST.get(attr.name)).pk)
                    # attr_desc['value'] = str(attr.attributevalue_set.get(pk=request.POST.get(attr.name)).pk)
                    attr_desc['value_name'] = str(attr.dict.model_class().objects.get(pk=request.POST.get(attr.name)).name)
                    # attr_desc['value_name'] = attr.attributevalue_set.get(pk=request.POST.get(attr.name)).vallue

                else:
                    attr_desc['value'] = request.POST.get(attr.name)
                    attr_desc['value_name'] = request.POST.get(attr.name)

                attr_desc['ordering'] = attr.ordering
                attr_desc['filtering'] = attr.filtering
                attr_dic[attr.name] = attr_desc

         form.instance.attributes = attr_dic
         form.save()

         if region is None:
             p, updated = request.user.userprofiletable_set.update(adress_state= form.cleaned_data['state'] ,adress_city =form.cleaned_data['city'] )

         if (contact_phone == '' or contact_phone !=phone_number):
             p, updated = request.user.userprofiletable_set.update(phone=phone_number)

         if is_auction=='on':
            p, created =Auction.objects.get_or_create(product=form.instance,title=form.instance.name,description=request.POST.get("description_auct", ""),
                                                      start_price=request.POST.get("start_price", ""),
                                                      end_price=request.POST.get("end_price", ""),
                                                      min_price_step=request.POST.get("min_price_step", ""),
                                                      end_date=request.POST.get("end_date", ""),
                                                      currency=form.instance.currency)

         return redirect(url)
```

Trace

```
    TypeError at /callboard/createadv/
'int' object is not iterable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/callboard/createadv/?next=/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'int' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /Users/korablevop/PycharmProjects/naxodu/callboard/views.py in createadv, line 259
Python Executable:  /Users/korablevop/.virtualenvs/mynewenv/bin/python
```

[image]

Comment: Please, post the traceback

Comment: Where is you assigning data to `region` var ?

Comment: the only place you're doing an iteration is `for attr in form.cleaned_data['subcategory']...` so I guess that's where you error happens. Since you don't tell us how `subcategory` is defined I have no idea if `subcategory.attributes.all()` might return an `int`. Please either post the traceback or look at the exact place the error occurs and try give us more succinct information.

Comment: if no one of if condition is True it works without any error.